# Calculator returns 0.0 to all questions asked

Tags: java, swing

I have some problems with the creation of a simple calculator, but when asking a question (like 2-1) the system returns 0.0 as the result. I am thinking that I am not using a good way to analise information. This is how I try to set the double 't' to the number inside the textbox.

```
insert = new JTextField();
insert.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        try {
            i = insert.getText();
            t = Double.parseDouble(i);
        } finally {}
    }; {}
});
insert.setBackground(new Color(135, 206, 235));
insert.setText("0");
insert.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 18));
insert.setColumns(10);
insert.setBounds(0, 50, 292, 28);
frame.getContentPane().add(insert);
```

If the mistake is not there, this is the full code:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.InputMethodListener;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.awt.event.InputMethodEvent;

public class Window {
    double t, x, a, l, s;
    String w, i;
    Scanner dati = new Scanner(System. in );
    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextField result;
    private JTextField insert;
    private JTextField hint;
    private JTextField score;
    private final JButton help = new JButton("?");
    private final JButton calculator = new JButton("=");

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Window window = new Window();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public Window() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(135, 206, 235));
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        calculator.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (l < 6 && l > 0) {
                    if (l != 2 && l != 3 && l != 4 && l != 5); {
                        s = x + t;
                    }
                    if (l != 1 && l != 3 && l != 4 && l != 5); {
                        s = x - t;
                    }
                    if (l != 1 && l != 2 && l != 4 && l != 5); {
                        s = x * t;
                    }
                    if (l != 1 && l != 2 && l != 3 && l != 5); {
                        s = x / t;
                    }
                    if (l != 1 && l != 2 && l != 4 && l != 3); {
                        s = (x / 100) * t;
                    }
                    result.setText(Double.toString(s));
                } else {
                    result.setText("Kļūda programmā :(");
                }
                t = 0;
                x = 0;
                l = 0;
                a = 0;
            }
        });
        calculator.setBounds(292, 57, 52, 20);
        frame.getContentPane().add(calculator);
        calculator.setBackground(new Color(135, 206, 235));
        help.setBackground(new Color(135, 206, 235));
        help.setBounds(292, 0, 52, 20);
        frame.getContentPane().add(help);

        score = new JTextField();
        score.setEditable(false);
        score.setText("\u0160eit rezult\u0101ts");
        score.setColumns(10);
        score.setBounds(344, 0, 100, 20);
        frame.getContentPane().add(score);

        hint = new JTextField();
        hint.setEditable(false);
        hint.setText("\u0160eit tavi skait\u013Ci");
        hint.setBounds(344, 57, 100, 20);
        frame.getContentPane().add(hint);
        hint.setColumns(10);

        insert = new JTextField();
        insert.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    i = insert.getText();
                    t = Double.parseDouble(i);
                } finally {}
            }; {}
        });
        insert.setBackground(new Color(135, 206, 235));
        insert.setText("0");
        insert.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        insert.setColumns(10);
        insert.setBounds(0, 50, 292, 28);
        frame.getContentPane().add(insert);

        result = new JTextField();
        result.setEditable(false);
        result.setBackground(new Color(135, 206, 235));
        result.setBounds(0, 0, 292, 28);
        result.setText("Hei!");
        result.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        frame.getContentPane().add(result);
        result.setColumns(10);

        JButton add = new JButton("+");
        add.setBackground(new Color(135, 206, 250));
        add.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                if (a != 0) {
                    x = x + t;
                    t = 0;
                    l = 1;
                } else {
                    x = t;
                    t = 0;
                    a = 1;
                    l = 1;
                }
            }
        });
        add.setBounds(0, 28, 89, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(add);

        JButton subtract = new JButton("-");
        subtract.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (a != 0) {
                    x = x - t;
                    t = 0;
                    l = 2;
                } else {
                    x = t;
                    t = 0;
                    a = 1;
                    l = 2;
                }
            }
        });
        subtract.setBackground(new Color(135, 206, 235));
        subtract.setBounds(89, 28, 89, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(subtract);

        JButton multiply = new JButton("x");
        multiply.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (a != 0) {
                    x = x * t;
                    t = 0;
                    l = 3;
                } else {
                    x = t;
                    t = 0;
                    a = 1;
                    l = 3;
                }
            }
        });
        multiply.setBackground(new Color(135, 206, 235));
        multiply.setForeground(new Color(0, 0, 0));
        multiply.setBounds(178, 28, 89, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(multiply);

        JButton divide = new JButton("/");
        divide.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (a != 0) {
                    x = x / t;
                    t = 0;
                    l = 4;
                } else {
                    x = t;
                    t = 0;
                    a = 1;
                    l = 4;
                }
            }
        });
        divide.setBackground(new Color(135, 206, 235));
        divide.setBounds(266, 28, 89, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(divide);

        JButton percent = new JButton("%");
        percent.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (a != 0) {
                    x = (x / 100) * t;
                    t = 0;
                    l = 5;
                } else {
                    x = t;
                    t = 0;
                    a = 1;
                    l = 5;
                }
            }
        });
        percent.setBackground(new Color(135, 206, 235));
        percent.setBounds(355, 28, 89, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(percent);
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 460, 115);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        dati.close();
    }
}
```

Possibly I am using a bad way to calculate.

If you want a simple explanation, I am trying to create a calculator with five functions - +, -, *, /, % - and has one text box to insert the numbers you want to calculate - insert, click function button, insert, click function button, when done - the = button. '?' button is planned to give a description of the calculator. I am making it for a school project, by the way.

Thanks in advance.

P.S. Kļūda programmā translates to fault in program.

Comment: I'd be reluctant to discard any parsing exceptions in the way that you do. At least write the exception message to stderr. This could help identify the problem.

Comment: If that was my code, i'd put a JLabel somewhere displaying all values of x,t,a,l and update in every actionPerformed

Comment: I want to notify that it is usually not a good practise to have a really huge method, split it up by implementing classes for the action listeners; it cleans the code up for a bit

Answer (score 3):

On your `actionListener` you have a `;` before each `{` on the `if` statements. Also, your conditions are strange, change it from this. And add `else` statements or a `switch`

```
calculator.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (l < 6 && l > 0) {
            if (l != 2 && l != 3 && l != 4 && l != 5); {
                s = x + t;
            }
            if (l != 1 && l != 3 && l != 4 && l != 5); {
                s = x - t;
            }
            if (l != 1 && l != 2 && l != 4 && l != 5); {
                s = x * t;
            }
            if (l != 1 && l != 2 && l != 3 && l != 5); {
                s = x / t;
            }
            if (l != 1 && l != 2 && l != 4 && l != 3); {
                s = (x / 100) * t;
            }
            result.setText(Double.toString(s));
        } else {
            result.setText("Kļūda programmā :(");
        }
        t = 0;
        x = 0;
        l = 0;
        a = 0;
    }
});
```

To this:

```
calculator.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (l < 6 && l > 0) {
            if (l == 1) {
                s = x + t;
            } else if (l == 2) {
                s = x - t;
            } else if (l == 3) {
                s = x * t;
            } else if (l == 4) {
                s = x / t;
            } else if (l == 5) {
                s = (x / 100) * t;
            }
            result.setText(Double.toString(s));
        } else {
            result.setText("Kļūda programmā :(");
        }
        t = 0;
        x = 0;
        l = 0;
        a = 0;
    }
});
```

Or this one (Recommended):

```
calculator.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        switch (l) {
            case 1:
                s = x + t;
                result.setText(Double.toString(s));
                break;
            case 2:
                s = x - t;
                result.setText(Double.toString(s));
                break;
            case 3:
                s = x * t;
                result.setText(Double.toString(s));
                break;
            case 4:
                s = x / t;
                result.setText(Double.toString(s));
                break;
            case 5:
                s = (x / 100) * t;
                result.setText(Double.toString(s));
                break;
            default:
                result.setText("Kļūda programmā :(");
                break;
        }
        t = 0;
        x = 0;
        l = 0;
        a = 0;
    }
});
```

And as an aside recommendation avoid using Null Layout, instead use a [Layout Manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) or combinations of them. This will prevent bugs since Swing was designed to work with them. For more information about this read [Why is it frowned upon to use a null layout in swing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592468/why-is-it-frowned-upon-to-use-a-null-layout-in-swing). Also please check [The use of multiple JFrames, Good / Bad Practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-bad-practice)

---

## Edit

To get a very similar view from your program and get it to work, you could try something like this, which doesn't use a null layout and prints the value each time you clic the `+` button. All the rest of buttons don't work yet (See how my code works with these buttons and take this logic to the rest of them):

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
public class LayoutExample {
    double number = 0;
    JFrame frame;
    JLabel label;
    JTextField field;
    JButton add, substract, mult, divide, total, help, perc;
    JPanel topPane, buttonPane, fieldPane;
    LayoutExample() {
        frame = new JFrame("Calculator");
        label = new JLabel("Result: ");
        field = new JTextField("0");
        add = new JButton("+");
        substract = new JButton("-");
        mult = new JButton("*");
        divide = new JButton("/");
        total = new JButton("=");
        perc = new JButton("%");
        help = new JButton("?");
        topPane = new JPanel();
        buttonPane = new JPanel();
        fieldPane = new JPanel();
        
        field.setColumns(10);
        
        topPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        buttonPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        fieldPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        
        topPane.add(label);
        topPane.add(help);
        
        add.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    number += Integer.parseInt(field.getText());
                } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                    nfe.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        
        total.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                label.setText("Result: " + number);
            }
        });
        
        buttonPane.add(add);
        buttonPane.add(substract);
        buttonPane.add(mult);
        buttonPane.add(divide);
        buttonPane.add(perc);
        
        fieldPane.add(field);
        fieldPane.add(total);
        
        frame.add(topPane, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        frame.add(buttonPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(fieldPane, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new LayoutExample();
    }
}
```

The output is very similar to the one you did as you can see:

[image]

Comment: Hello. Whilst this is something useful, my problem is still not fixed. Currently I am seeing that the double 't' is 0.0 the whole time, and is not changing... is there any way I can fix that? By the way, I am a massive Java rookie - I've been coding in Java, or in a wider scale - outside of Scratch - for around 3 days... so help would be appreciated.

Comment: @Artis please post a [Runnable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) your code is A LOT and I don't have enough time to check it all. Make a simple copy of this one with the minimum code so I can check the issue there, it'll be easier to find then. I don't know what you mean or where you're seeing a double 't' ?

Comment: I've checked it and I'm afraid to tell you, that you **must** redo the whole program, as is, it will be harder and take more time for me / you / anyone who wants to help you with this to fix it. Better create a new one from scratch and avoid using null layout. Once you have it, please post another question with the minimum code to test it